# Meaning of "buy" in "I don't buy this person answering your mobile."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The following sentence is meaningless to me. What is the meaning of "buy" here?

> I don't ***buy*** this person answering your mobile.

It sounds like "*trust*" to me, but I have never seen this meaning of "***buy***".

Comment: Empty of context, references, source and research. This could have been an *excellent* question...pity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In casual or informal English we can say we don't 'buy' (accept, agree to) an idea if we mean that we don't believe that it is likely or probable.

In the question, the speaker does not accept the **idea** of 'this person' **answering the other person's mobile (cell) phone.**

If you tell your teacher that a dog ate your homework, it is quite possible that he or she will not buy that (i.e. buy your explanation).

> buy verb (BELIEVE) [ T ]
> informal
> to believe that something is true:
>
> She'll never buy that story about you getting lost!

[Buy (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/buy)

Comment: Is it used though with a person as object? "I don't buy this person"? I am not a native speaker, but I have been living in the UK for 16 years. Never heard it.

Comment: I don't buy [the idea of] **this person answering your mobile**.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was a bit confused by the title of the question. I will see if I can edit it.

Comment: @fev can't speak to the UK, but certainly in the US it is not uncommon

Comment: @eps Good to know. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+don%27t+buy+him%2CI+don%27t+buy+it%2CI+don%27t+buy+this+person&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20do%20not%20buy%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20do%20not%20buy%20it%3B%2Cc0) shows that in AmE  this sentence ( I don't buy this person) is not encountered in written texts. Very rare instances of "I don't buy him". But slang is not written, so I believe you if you say so.

Comment: If you consider 'buy this person' as a phrase on its own, where does that leave 'answering your mobile'?

Comment: "But slang is not written" - who says? "Dear Joe, I don't think the boss bought your story about why the report was late. Best regards, Mike"

Comment: It's almost always used as, "I don't buy [it/that]". The example question, as it is written in the title, is very awkward to a native speaker.

Comment: @TonyArra - Often used that way, but I think 'almost always' is overstating the situation. Random Google search "An officer in Balch Spring, Texas, was convicted of murder last August and sentenced to 15 years after **a jury didn't buy his explanation** that he was trying to protect his partner when he fired into a car full of black teenagers, striking a 15-year-old." (ABC News). Also "Who said **he didn't "buy" that he and other PGA players could have done more** to bring blacks into private golf" (James Corrigan on Twitter).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I meant that NGram searches in books, and slang is more rarely used in books. It is more used in speech. eps said they use "I don't buy a person" in AmE, so I got curious.

Comment: @fev: There are two sources of confusion here! Firstly, the object is not _this person_, it is _this person answering your mobile_. And that means, in this context, the _idea_ that this person answered your mobile (as Michael Harvey says in a comment). Secondly, _this person answering your mobile_ can also mean _the person who is answering your mobile_, but that is not what it means here.

Answer (score 2):

"Buy" in this sense means "Believe" or more broadly, "accept" or "support."

"I don't buy that she was sick" -- she told people she was sick, but I don't believe it.

It can also be phrased as "buy into". According to the Cambridge Dictionary: "If you buy into an idea or plan, you give it your support or agree with it."

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: *I'm leaving this answer up in case it's something people can learn from, but **it is incorrect**. As people in the comments have noted, I interpreted "this person answering your mobile" as a noun phrase, but that probably isn't what the question-asker meant. "Buy" in this case can have its usual meaning of "believe that X (that this person is answering your mobile) is true).*

As a native speaker (US), I've never seen "buy" used that way either, but I would make the same guess as you: That it means "trust". To me, you can only use that type of "buy" to mean "trust *what the person is saying*." So it is odd to say "buy [the person]" rather than to say something like "buy their story" / "buy their spiel", etc.

However, given that we can use "believe" in both contexts ("I don't believe his story." "I don't believe him.") it doesn't seem that crazy to me if some speakers have started using "buy" in both contexts too.

Comment: I'm also a native US speaker, and I've heard (and spoken) it.  Maybe it's a regional thing.    The meaning is that someone is trying to "sell" you something (in OP's example, the idea that it's perfectly innocent that *this person* answered *your* cell phone).  And you're not buying it.

Comment: It's a mistake to focus on the 'I don't buy _this person_ (period)' interpretation. The actual question asked about 'I don't buy _this person doing something_.

Comment: If I say 'I don't buy Donald Trump being fluent in Catalan/being the next US National Soccer Team captain/being the reincarnation of Geoffrey Chaucer', it would be a misreading to fixate on 'I don't buy Donald Trump'.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the phrase "this person answering your mobile" as a noun phrase referring to a person (which would mean the sentence could be rephrased as "I don't buy this person who is answering your mobile"), instead of as a sort of clause referring to an event or assertion (which would mean the sentence could be rephrased as "I don't buy the assertion that this person answered your mobile").

Comment: "I would make the same guess as you: That it means "trust"." - I didn't 'guess'; I looked in a dictionary. That's how we answer on here.

Comment: Tanner, yes that's exactly what happened. I see now that it's ambiguous. And Michael, no need for snark. We should use dictionaries, but given that I thought this was a usage that isn't in dictionaries, I thought the best we could do was guess at how a stretched version of the dictionary-established usage would fit. Thank you for the correction, though.